# Route Navigation issue when using route guard

Tags: angular7, angular-routing

I have a route guard:

```ts
          import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ConfigurationService } from "./../configuration.service";
import { LoginServiceService } from '../login-service.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  activate = false;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginServiceService,
    private router: Router,
    private configService:ConfigurationService
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.loginService.userRights().pipe(
      map((userRights) => {
        this.filterUserRights(userRights['rights'])
      }),
    );
  }

  filterUserRights(userRights:Array<string>):Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(userRights)
    const requiredRights = ['create_organisation', 'create_tenant', 'create_user'];
    if (requiredRights.some((right) => userRights && userRights.includes(right))) {
      this.activate = true;
    } else {
      this.activate = false;
    }
    return of(this.activate);
  }

}
```

I have a parent route like :

```ts
  { path: "", redirectTo: "mylearning", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "managepeople",
    component: ManagepeopleComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard],

    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "organisations", pathMatch: "full" },
      {
        path: "organisations",
        component: OrganisationsComponent,
        data: {
          animation: "organisations"
        },

      },
]
}
```

Im using the role guard on parent route managepeople. The problem is that when i refresh the browser for ex, on route : managepeople/organisations,
it does not go to that route but redirects to the root component url.The user rights comes from a service which will take some to be fetched from server.
How do i fix this?

My service function:

```ts
  userRights() {
    var uiRolesUrl = this.config.restRequestUrl + "userapi/myrights/";
    var observable = this.http.get(uiRolesUrl);
    return observable;
  }
```

Comment: Return an *observable* of a Boolean, so that it can wait for the service data before deciding.

Comment: not sure. lol..how do i retuen as observable?

Comment: Observable.of(_)

Comment: Right, but then you just get an observable of the same (wrong) value you already have. You need the *service* to provide the data as an observable, then map from that, so that the result only resolves once you have the information you need.

Comment: i have edited my question with latest code.Rn,its showing same problem

Comment: That's exactly what I told you, and not what the answer suggests.

Comment: what should i change in this code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002977/route-navigation-issue-when-using-route-guard#comment98652041_56002977

Comment: Also you need to return an observable, not subscribe.

Comment: I have updated my question with the service function call.

Comment: But canActivate doesn't actually pass on the observable. Read the answer more carefully; does it subscribe in the guard?

Comment: You mean the answer posted here by uapasha?

Comment: There is only one answer, yes.

Comment: when i try the code,im unable to use pipe. this.loginService.userRights.pipe is not a function error

Comment: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<Object>'

Comment: Right, because you're not *calling* the function that returns the observable. Read the message! `() => Observable<Object>` is a callable returning an observable, not an observable itself, so doesn't have a `.pipe` method.

Comment: How to return observable of the same?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. I've already dedicated enough of my time to this - I'd suggest you read up more on using observables and TypeScript. Good luck.

Comment: Im not asking, if you can help,itll be good,anyways thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ConfigurationService } from "./../configuration.service";
import { LoginServiceService } from '../login-service.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
  activate = false;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginServiceService,
    private router: Router,
    private configService:ConfigurationService
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.loginService.userRights().pipe(map((userRights) => {
      return this.filterUserRights(userRights['rights']);
    }),
    )
  }

  filterUserRights(userRights:Array<string>){
    const requiredRights = ['create_organisation', 'create_tenant', 'create_user'];
    if (requiredRights.some((right) => userRights && userRights.includes(right))) {
      this.activate = true;
    } else {
      this.activate = false;
    }
    return this.activate;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the canActivate can return Observable or Promise which allows for asynchronous operations. So you need to write it in an async manner to handle the case when user role is not yet fetched. Something like:

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.configService.userRights) {
      return this.filterUserRighs(this.configService.userRights);
    }

    return this.configService.getUserRights.pipe(
      map((userRights) => {
        return this.filterUserRighs(userRights);
      }),
    );
  }

  filterUserRighs(userRights) {
    const requiredRights = ['create_organisation', 'create_tenant', 'create_user'];

    if (requiredRights.some((right) => userRights && userRights.includes(right))) {
      this.activate = true;
    } else {
      this.activate = false;
    }
    return this.activate;
  }
```

Comment: @MohitHarshan if (this.configService.userRights) will always return true, because in your code it is a function.

by `this.configService.userRights` I meant current user right already fetched by the service